# Android diagonal triangle buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I am working on an android application.

I need to have 2 buttons but similar to the following picture.

[image]

The red triangle is a button and the yellow is another button.

How can this be achieved?

Is there a way to do it other than having it as 1 picture and then checking the touch position? because that would involve a lot of math and might not be precise. Also if I use this method I cannot have a clicked state on the each button seperatly. (like when the button grays out on touch down)

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I think you might be in for a tough challenge. You can certainly do this using OpenGL ES to define your triangles and even add touch capability but it's complex. Take a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html there's even an example for drawing a triangle in one of the lessons and how to handle touch events. I can't help any further though as I've never used OpenGL ES.

Comment: @Squonk It can definitely be done without OpenGL just by using drawables, however separating the 2 buttons seems impossible.

Comment: refer this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482484/android-triangle-custom-buttons/30484166#30484166][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482484/android-triangle-custom-buttons/30484166#30484166

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482484/android-triangle-custom-buttons/30484166