# Android triangle custom buttons

Tags: android, button, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I want to make 2 diagonal triangle buttons like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315400/android-diagonal-triangle-buttons).

How can I achieve this? Should I make a drawable xml with a rectangle and rotate it somehow? Should I make an image and make it clickable only on the triangle parts with the help of mathematics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    package com.example.buttonsView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Path.FillType;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class TwoButtons extends View {

    private Path path;
    private Path path1;
    private Region region;
    private Region region1;
    private static int GAP=10;

    private ButtonClickEvents buttonClickEvent;

    public interface ButtonClickEvents{
        public void redButtonClick();
        public void blueButtonClick();
    }

    public void setOnButtonClickEvent(ButtonClickEvents buttonClickEvent) {
        this.buttonClickEvent=buttonClickEvent;
    }

    public TwoButtons(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);

        paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        Point a = new Point(GAP, GAP);
        Point b = new Point(GAP, getHeight()-2*GAP);
        Point c = new Point(getWidth()-2*GAP, GAP);

        path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
        path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
        path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        RectF rectF = new RectF();
        path.computeBounds(rectF, true);
        region = new Region();
        region.setPath(path, new Region((int) rectF.left, (int) rectF.top, (int) rectF.right, (int) rectF.bottom));

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Point a1 = new Point(getWidth()-GAP, getHeight()-GAP);
        Point b1 = new Point(getWidth()-GAP, 2*GAP);
        Point c1 = new Point(2*GAP, getHeight()-GAP);

        path1 = new Path();
        path1.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path1.moveTo(a1.x, a1.y);
        path1.lineTo(b1.x, b1.y);
        path1.lineTo(c1.x, c1.y);

        path1.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path1, paint);

        RectF rectF1 = new RectF();
        path1.computeBounds(rectF1, true);
        region1 = new Region();
        region1.setPath(path1, new Region((int) rectF1.left, (int) rectF1.top, (int) rectF1.right, (int) rectF1.bottom));


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = (int) event.getX();
            point.y = (int) event.getY();

            invalidate();


            if(region.contains((int)point.x,(int) point.y))
            {
                if(buttonClickEvent!=null)
                    buttonClickEvent.redButtonClick();
            }else if(region1.contains((int)point.x,(int) point.y))
            {
                if(buttonClickEvent!=null)
                    buttonClickEvent.blueButtonClick();
            }

        return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.buttonsView.MainActivity" >

    <com.example.buttonsView.TwoButtons
        android:id="@+id/twoButtons1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.buttonsView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.afbb.preferencessample.R;
import com.example.buttonsView.TwoButtons.ButtonClickEvents;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TwoButtons buttons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttons = (TwoButtons) findViewById(R.id.twoButtons1);
        buttons.setOnButtonClickEvent(new ButtonClickEvents() {

            @Override
            public void redButtonClick() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "red",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void blueButtonClick() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "blue",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

output :

[image: output]

[image: output]

Comment: May be it will helpful l to you

Comment: Thanks Saved my day :)

Comment: @ravi This is awesome! I'm making some modifications and afterwards probably uploading to GitHub. Any objections ?